# Widget Layout for 960x540 and 854x480

Tags: android, layout, android-widget

Both of these sizes pull from the same layout folder.  So...I am wondering how I can create widget that looks good on both?  I have attached screen shots to show the 2 displays that are pulling the same resources.

[image: 960 x 540 Display 240 dpi]

[image: 854 x 480 Display 240 dpi]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Both of these sizes pull from the same layout folder.
```

In Android the layout was chosen based on the density of the Devices [Different Screen Configuration](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for eg:

(ldpi) screens (~120dpi).

(mdpi) screens (~160dpi).

(hdpi) screens (~240dpi).

(xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

Both  **960x540 and 854x480** falls in **hdpi layout** , so you are getting same layout for both one.

To solve this issues , to get apt UI for both specification create separate XML for both inside **hdpi-layout**. for eg: 960_540.xml and 854_480.xml

In Activity check the Screen Size of Device so that set corresponding ContentView

You can get Screen Size using **Display Metrics** below Code :

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    screenWidth = display.getWidth(); 
    screenHeight = display.getHeight();
    dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    String str_ScreenSize = dm.widthPixels + " x " + dm.heightPixels;
    str_ScreenSize = "dd" + " x " + dm.heightPixels;

    if(screenHeight==854 & screenwidth==480){
        setContentView(R.layout.854_480);
    }
    else if(screenHeight==960 && screenwidth==540){
        setContentView(R.layout.960_540);
    }
```

Comment: This is freaking horrible.  The dpi / size folder structure design for Android is one of the worst architectures of all time.  How hard would it be for Google to have only supported a specific set of DPI and screen size combinations?  C'mon man.