# Android xml-how to optimise layout for devices

Tags: xml, button, layout, screen-size

I have made a simple layout but I am having trouble optimising it for different screen sizes. I have made it look fine on a 5.1 device but the buttons are to small on 10.1 and to big on a 3.2 screen. I have tried failed and been frustrated with many possibilities but can't seem to find any that work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated thank you. Here is the code for my basic layout that look fine on a 5.1 inch screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home" 
android:background="@drawable/bg">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/playB"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true
    android:background="@drawable/menu_button"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/aboutB"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/playB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/playB"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"        
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_button"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/settingsB"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/playB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/aboutB"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"  
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_button"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dp is the right way. It wont be a constant size cuz AOS will scale dps using multiplier according to screen density. (btw dip==dp they are absolutely the same) so dps are density independent. However scaling is not enough usually. So you need to create separate resources for different screens and I might say that supporting multiple screens is a really very big pain in da @$$. Seems like the only one good and proper way is to use OpenGL... 
You might found following links helpful:
[How to use resource qualifier on layouts to distinguish smartphones like HTC Desire and Samsung Galaxy Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097955/how-to-use-resource-qualifier-on-layouts-to-distinguish-smartphones-like-htc-des?rq=1) 
[image size (drawable-hdpi/ldpi/mdpi/xhdpi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381965/image-size-drawable-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi-xhdpi) 
[Avoid Multiple Drawable Sets (hdpi/mdpi/ldpi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459799/avoid-multiple-drawable-sets-hdpi-mdpi-ldpi?rq=1) 
[Widget Layout for 960x540 and 854x480](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647948/widget-layout-for-960x540-and-854x480) 
[getDimension()/getDimensionPixelSize() - mutliplier issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368937/getdimension-getdimensionpixelsize-mutliplier) 
http://www.findbestopensource.com/product/svg-android

Comment: Thanks all of those I all helped heaps. Sorta new to android so glad there is people like you to help me out. I know it can be difficult getting the app size for different screens but I also know that it makes or breaks an apps reputation. Thanks again!!!

Comment: don't forget to choose an Answer when you'll be able to do that

Answer (score 0):

You used fixed `dp` size for your buttons, so they'll be constant size. That can make them too big on small screen and too small on large screen. I strongly encourage you to study how to design for [multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html). As for your problem, you can 1) set the button size using ratio of button width to screen width that you want. This has to be done programmatically to check devices dimension;  2) create different layouts for different screens like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Hey sounds great I might try to find how to program the layout properly. Any links or ideas on where I might find some specific information on this topic? Thanks for the reply greatly appreciated!!